# OutOfMemory while downloading a PDF file

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In an app I am making people can download a PDF file. On my Nexus 5 there is on problem when downloading the PDF but on an HTC One X I get an Out of Memory error. How can I avoid this? The code I am using is:

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
    String fileUrl = params[0];
    mFileName = params[1];
    mFolder = new File(mContext.getFilesDir(), "pdfs");
    mFolder.mkdir();

    Random r = new Random();
    int i1 = r.nextInt(99 - 10) + 99;
    mFile = new File(mFolder, mFileName + "." + i1);
    try {
        mFile.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        System.gc();
        URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.connect();

        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
        int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[MEGABYTE];
        int bufferLength = 0;
        long total = 0;
        while((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer))>0 ){
            total += bufferLength;

            int progress = (int)((total * 100) / totalSize);

            publishProgress(progress, (int)total, totalSize);
            fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
        }
        fileOutputStream.close();

        return true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        mFile.delete();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        mFile.delete();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        mFile.delete();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
    if(mOnDownloadListener != null) {
        File to = new File(mFolder, mFileName);
        mFile.renameTo(to);

        mOnDownloadListener.onDownloaded(success);
    }
    super.onPostExecute(success);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the memory usage of your app before and during the download? How large is the PDF? try http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html

Comment: When I am starting the download the Free memory is 2.04 MB and the allocated memory is 30.86 MB according to the Memory manager in Android Studio. When I start the download this shoots up but after a few seconds I get the following error `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=97228KB, Allocated=85604KB)`

Comment: Might be something with your code then. Try the DownloadManager-api I pasted above. Don't have time to look at the code atm.

Comment: Did you add android large heap true in your application tag

Comment: Oh, and btw, there should never be a reason to manually run GC, usually a pointer that something is horribly wrong.

Comment: I would reduce the size of your buffer to 16KB or 64KB, assuming that `MEGABYTE` is literal. Bear in mind that Android prior to 5.0 does not have a compacting garbage collector (and on 5.0+ it only compacts while your app is in the background), so `OutOfMemoryError` occurs when there is not a big enough block of free space for the requested allocation. Don't allocate big buffers unless you really need them, and for this, you shouldn't need it.

Comment: I do not use large heap true in my application. The problem occurs on Android 4.2, not 5.0.

Comment: Is it possible to do it without downloadmanager?